# How can I set a certain temperature on Redshift?

Tags: color-management

I just switched to Ubuntu, and on Windows I was using f.lux. I was able to set the temperature to a certain time and leave it at that, it wouldn't change at all.

Now I installed Redshift and I can't do that anymore. Could some one help, please?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can permanently set the color temperature from the command line:
Open (`gnome-`) `terminal`, type the command:

```
redshift -O <temperature>
```

and press <kbd>Return</kbd>

To set it to (e.g.) 3700:

```
redshift -O 3700
```

To reset to "neutral":

```
redshift -x
```

See for more (command line) options:

```
man redshift
```

(Given the fact that Redshift is installed :))

Comment: When I type redshift -O for example, it works for about a second, then goes back to normal... What should I do in this situation? edit: nevermind, i got it. thank you so much

Comment: @Richardplury I have same issue, it goes back after a sec. What did you solve it?

Comment: same here, always reverts back to defaults

Comment: You must disable Redshift in the top bar to set the temperature with the terminal. You can do this by clicking the icon and pressing Enabled to uncheck it. @eco_bach

Comment: I had to completely quit the top bar gtk app. I find redshift is a bit finnicky with starting multiple copies, not being able to distinguish between them properly.

Comment: ... alternatively run `pkill redshift` if it resets the color after some seconds, and after that `redshift -O 1234` again

Comment: If `redshift-gtk` runs at the same time as you use `redshift` from the terminal, then `redshift-gtk` will override any terminal command used. So first make sure to kill the `redshift-gtk` process.

Comment: I would love to know if there is a way to make this from the settings on the GUI. changing even this via terminal regularly seems a bit too much of linux for a normal user. I can't find any setting on the redshift icon.

Comment: @6005: looks like Redshift won't fix that [issue with multiple instances running at the same time](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/218) any time [soon](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/556).

Answer (score 32):

If you use `redshift-gtk` then @Jacob's method will not work.

You need to create a configuration file at `$HOME/.config/redshift.conf` to change it's settings. Sample configuration file creation described in it's [official page](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), quoted below:

> Configuration file
>
> A configuration file can be created, but the
> documentation is a bit sparse. You’ll have to create it manually and
> put it in ~/.config/redshift.conf. The following is an example of a
> configuration file:
>
> ```
> ; Global settings for redshift
> [redshift]
> ; Set the day and night screen temperatures
> temp-day=5700
> temp-night=3500
>
> ; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
> ; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
> ; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature.
> transition=1
>
> ; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0.
> ;brightness=0.9
> ; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night
> ; since version 1.8.
> ;brightness-day=0.7
> ;brightness-night=0.4
> ; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel
> ; individually)
> gamma=0.8
> ;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
> ; This can also be set individually for day and night since
> ; version 1.10.
> ;gamma-day=0.8:0.7:0.8
> ;gamma-night=0.6
>
> ; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'geoclue2', 'manual'
> ; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values.
> ; The location provider settings are in a different section.
> location-provider=manual
>
> ; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
> ; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values.
> ; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API.
> ; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
> ; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
> adjustment-method=randr
>
> ; Configuration of the location-provider:
> ; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings.
> ; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
> ; Keep in mind that longitudes west of Greenwich (e.g. the Americas)
> ; are negative numbers.
> [manual]
> lat=48.1
> lon=11.6
>
> ; Configuration of the adjustment-method
> ; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings.
> ; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
> ; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
> ; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the
> ; second screen. If this option is not specified, Redshift will try
> ; to adjust _all_ screens.
> [randr]
> screen=1
> ```

Another sample configuration also found at [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift).

Answer (score 4):

For those who are looking for answer to this question 
"When I type `redshift -O` for example, it works for about a second, then goes back to norma‍l... What should I do in this situation? "

Try - Go to the top of your screen -> The redshift icon -> Click on Enable to disable it -> the go on terminal and type

```
redshift -O <Temperature>
```

Worked for me

Comment: Note that -o is an "o" (letter) and not the "0" (number.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Redshift GTK (and normal `redshift`) can be run with options to specify how it is run:

```
 redshift-gtk -l 52.6:1.6 -t 5700:3500 -g 0.82 -m randr -v
```

In the above command these commands are used:

- `-l` specifies your locations rough coordinates, so it can sync with sunrise/sunset. Usually redshift-gtk tries looking up your location but this won't work unles your computer has GPS so it easier to set manually, using a mapping service to give a approximation of your location (e.g. with [with OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=52.61365&mlon=1.64417&zoom=15#map=17/52.61336/1.64476))
- `-t` sets the [color temperature](https://en..wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) of the screen, for day and for night respectively.
- `-g` sets the gamma correction apply
- `-m` the method to use. This will likely depend on your desktop compositor.
- `-b` can also be used to set screen brightness (also `DAY:NIGHT`, with values between `.1` & `1`.

This works largely the same as `redshift` (and uses pretty much the same options as in `man redshift`), except it runs with a icon so you can turn it off with switching to terminal. You can run the above command in a terminal, your desktops command launcher (usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), or even [create a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop).

Otherwise it may be better to use a configuration file as in @Mahmudul Hasan Shohag's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Debian 10 (KDE), I solved the "1 second issue" going to:

System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart > double-click on Redshift > Application > Change "Command:" line "redshift-gtk" to "redshift -O 3700" (without quotes)

That changed the temperature permanently.