# Automatically and progressively dim and warm screen

Tags: display, brightness, redshift

I would like to automatically dim the screen from 100% to 20% and get the color temperature from 5000 K to 2000 K. It should be progressive from 8pm to 11pm and it should turn off at 5am.
Here are some related questions pointing to a possible solution:

[How to set a certain temperature on Redshift?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565963/how-can-i-set-a-certain-temperature-on-redshift).

[Custom transition hours with cronjob](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991832/redshift-configuration-how-to-set-fixed-transition-hours)

[Automatically adjust display brightness based on sunrise and sunset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/894460/automatically-adjust-display-brightness-based-on-sunrise-and-sunset/894470#894470)

Comment: Check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Redshift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a certain temperature on Redshift?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565963/how-can-i-set-a-certain-temperature-on-redshift)

Comment: How do you properly configure it? Because I've installed it with the default configuration and it doesn't finds any screen.