# Make screen yellow (read mode like in Xiaomi phone)

Tags: productivity

I want to try if it can increase my reading productivity.

Comment: Redshift already installed, it only change brightness based on times and the "Yellow" is still not yellow as in my Xiaomi phone.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/565963/how-can-i-set-a-certain-temperature-on-redshift?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some software like f.lux, you can install it by typing in terminal:

```
wget -c https://justgetflux.com/linux/xflux64.tgz
tar -xvzf xflux64.tgz
rm -rf xflux64.tgz
sudo cp xflux /usr/bin/
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/xflux
```

Note: I supossed that you have a 64bit version.