# How to make redshift even more red in Ubuntu MATE 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, colors, redshift

I am using Ubuntu MATE 22.04. Towards night, redshift sets a color temperature of 4500K.

How to reduce the color temperature even further? Unlike the Night Light feature in GNOME/KDE, Redshift does not have any simple method to manually change the color temperature (but it might be configurable by editing `redshift.conf`, which is why I am asking this question).

Comment: I set mine to `3200K` in the `.config/redshift.conf` file on the `temp-night=` line.

Comment: There is both a `temp-day` and `temp-night` setting... my choice is =3500, but `man redshift` provides a pretty good clue on my *lunar* box.

Comment: As you can see in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/864845/167115), you can use the config file to set the temperature to something lower like 3500.

Comment: Using an edited version of the default configuration file, I have `[redshift]` and `temp-day=3400` and `temp-night=3400` and `transition=1` and `location-provider=manual` with the default `[manual]` and `lat=48.1` and `lon=11.6` All the other lines are commented out (with a `;` at the beginning of all commented out lines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand (or to provide some contrast compared to the answer found in the [duplicate post](https://askubuntu.com/a/864845/167115)). Here's what I have in my `~/.config/redshift.conf` file:

```
; Global settings for redshift
[redshift]
; Set the day and night screen temperatures
temp-day=3400
temp-night=3400

; Enable/Disable a smooth transition between day and night
; 0 will cause a direct change from day to night screen temperature.
; 1 will gradually increase or decrease the screen temperature.
transition=1

; Set the screen brightness. Default is 1.0.
;brightness=0.9
; It is also possible to use different settings for day and night
; since version 1.8.
;brightness-day=0.7
;brightness-night=0.4
; Set the screen gamma (for all colors, or each color channel
; individually)
;gamma=0.8
;gamma=0.8:0.7:0.8
; This can also be set individually for day and night since
; version 1.10.
;gamma-day=0.8:0.7:0.8
;gamma-night=0.6

; Set the location-provider: 'geoclue', 'geoclue2', 'manual'
; type 'redshift -l list' to see possible values.
; The location provider settings are in a different section.
location-provider=manual

; Set the adjustment-method: 'randr', 'vidmode'
; type 'redshift -m list' to see all possible values.
; 'randr' is the preferred method, 'vidmode' is an older API.
; but works in some cases when 'randr' does not.
; The adjustment method settings are in a different section.
;adjustment-method=randr

; Configuration of the location-provider:
; type 'redshift -l PROVIDER:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -l manual:help'
; Keep in mind that longitudes west of Greenwich (e.g. the Americas)
; are negative numbers.
[manual]
lat=48.1
lon=11.6

; Configuration of the adjustment-method
; type 'redshift -m METHOD:help' to see the settings.
; ex: 'redshift -m randr:help'
; In this example, randr is configured to adjust screen 1.
; Note that the numbering starts from 0, so this is actually the
; second screen. If this option is not specified, Redshift will try
; to adjust _all_ screens.
; [randr]
; screen=1
```

I have everything commented out except for:

```
[redshift]
temp-day=3400
temp-night=3400
transition=1
location-provider=manual
[manual]
lat=48.1
lon=11.6
```

I have both `temp-day` and `temp-night` set to `3400`. You can adjust these accordingly.

`transition=1` is probably not necessary for me because I have day and night set to the same value but this may be of interest to you.

`location-provider=manual` is kind of important as the automatic methods usually fail and redshift will fail to start.

- If you have night and day set to different temperatures, you should determine your latitude (`lat`) and longitude (`lon`) and set these accordingly.
- Of course: if day and night are set to the same temperature, you can leave these at the default coordinates (`41.8` and `11.6`).

Comment: Somehow the automatic location works for me. But otherwise, thanks for the answer

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I believe the automatic works when you have the `geoclue-2.0` package installed.  If you also install the `geoclue-2-demo` you can see if the `geoclue-2.0` is working properly when you get output from running `/usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/where-am-i`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Even with geoclue working, I've had problems with redshift where there is an error on startup and then the fix is to reinstall geoclue-2.0 which can be kind of annoying. It seems to happen randomly but I haven't looked into why the problem occurs. Of course if you encounter this problem in the future, you can set the coordinates manually to avoid the issue.